# calculate expiration date using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write a code to calculate expiration dates automatically using vba.
I have a database with a list of employees, each employee has a list of trainings with their dates and expiration dates.
I want to add new training to each person by clicking on a button to add the training name and the date, and the expiration date must be calculated automatically (knowing that each training has one year of validity)

I’ve written this code so far:

```
    Public repertoire As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    repertoire = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    
   

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
Form_Intern =uF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Intern.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Intern.ListIndex, 0)
Date_Form_Intern = UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Intern.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Intern.ListIndex, 1)
fin_col_Form_Intern = ws.Cells(10, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Cells(10, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = Form_Intern ' training name 
ws.Cells(11, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = CDate(Date_Form_Intern) ' date
ws.Cells(15, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = CDate(Date_Form_Intern + 1095) ' expiration date
ws.Cells(12, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = repertoire
Me.Hide
Unload Me
   
End Sub
```

The problem in my code is on the line

```
 ws.Cells(15, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = CDate(Date_Form_Intern + 1095) ' expiration date
```

it says type mismatch

Can anyone tell me where is the mistake, thank you.

Comment: Do you need to add an year to `ExpirationDate`? What `1095` should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Date_Form_Intern` looks to be a string. You cannot add a Long to a string.

To avoid the error you must change it in:

```
ws.Cells(15, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = CDate(Date_Form_Intern) + 1095
```

But why adding 1095?

If you must add a Year to `Date_Form_Intern` (as Date), then test the next function, please:

```
Function ExpirationDate(Date_Form_Intern As Date) As Date
   ExpirationDate = DateSerial(Year(Date_Form_Intern) + 1, _
             Month(Date_Form_Intern), Day(Date_Form_Intern))
End Function
```

The function can be called in your code as following:

```
ws.Cells(15, fin_col_Form_Intern + 1) = ExpirationDate(CDate(Date_Form_Intern))
```

Comment: Thank you very much I used your function and it works perfectly quick and easy

Comment: @FaruSZ: Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody spends some time for us and supply a solution to our question, vote the answer up and even more important, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In such a case, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer worked...